# asp mvc file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload

I have a form in asp.net mvc 3 project with some properties (a name and some extra properties who need to be filled in).

What i also need is a file to upload in the same form.

I placed an input type "file" and that works when i use Request.File the file is ok.

But i'm also using form validation, so when my name is not filled in, it's not possible to save. That works fine, but then my file is cleared..

Someone who has a good example to use file upload in a form? (with other fields and validation)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Neil Knight's excellent references in his answer, if you're using ajax (and you probably are or will be to leverage MVC's ability to facilitate partial page refreshes) the jquery plugin [here](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) has proved itself useful in enabling file upload without a full page navigation.